# Call Activity's function from OnClick()

Tags: android, android-activity, onclick, runtime, android-context

I have that code:

```
public class GeolocationActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements SensorEventListener {
{
    //...

    private void setUpCompass()
    {
        isCompass = true;
        setContentView(R.layout.subactivity_compass);
        //...
    }

    private void setUpMain()
    {
        //...

        btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.geoloc_compass);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // here I want to call method setUpCompass();
            }
        });
        //...

    }           
}
```

I want to call `setUpCompass()` method from `onClick()` function in `setUpMain()`.

I tried:

```
Context c = getBaseContext();
((GeolocationActivity)c).setUpCompass();
```

but I get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ContextImpl cannot be cast to com.myname.myapp.GeolocationActivity
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm confused. What's wrong with simply calling `setUpCompass()`?

Comment: It is not member of OnClickListener

Comment: It still has access to it. Did you try calling it that way?

Comment: Yes, if I good remember. And saw error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead simply use `GeolocationActivity.this`.

Example:

```
GeolocationActivity.this.setUpCompass();
```